# Xcode 4 destination and schemes

Tags: xcode, ios

I've recently migrated from Xcode 3 to 4, and now I'm a bit confused. If I connect a device with name say ottoPhone and iOS version 4.2.1, there show up six entries in the scheme drop down list, namely
ottoPhone (4.2.1)
ottoPhone (4.2.1)
ottoPhone (4.2.1)
ottoPhone (4.2.1)
ottoPhone (4.2.1)
ottoPhone (4.2.1, overiding Base SDK to 4.3)

Compiling works only for the last two selections (the one with overiding and the one directly preceding it). For the other selections I get errors like stdarg.h and float.h are missing (where those files are included fom CoreFoundation.h in SDK 3.0). So, I presume these selections are using different base SDKs.

How can I show more information about such a selection, namely what SDK is in use for instance? My deployment target is set to iOS 3.1, I think...

Answer (score 0):

If you click that same drop down and select the "Edit Scheme" option you'll be able to see information about the selected scheme. By selecting the "Manage Schemes" option you'll be able to delete any that you don't need, which you might want to do since it sounds like you have a few duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Select the little folder icon near the top left, just under the 'Run' button (it's in the middle in this little screenshot):

  [image: build setting]
- This will now show a blue icon representing your project just underneath it (also visible above in the screenshot).
- Double click on the blue icon, this will launch a new window.  Choose the 'Build Settings' tab at the top.
- Look for the option you want.  This is easier if you use the search box at the top right.  Search for 'deployment target' to find the deployment target setting.